set working Q in connect giving error while using intent based routing
set working Q block in amazon connect giving error while set attribute block sharing value.
set attribute block
set working Q
"ContactFlowName": "products Inbound",
    "ContactFlowModuleType": "SetAttributes",
    "Identifier": "6ddd0570-bdc6-4f35-a1dc-0a597ff721cb",
    "Timestamp": "2024-09-10T10:28:12.863Z",
    "Parameters": {
        "Value": "Storage",
        "AddAttributeToRelatedContact": "false",
        "Key": "LexInputIntent"

.....
"ContactFlowName": "products Inbound",
    "ContactFlowModuleType": "SetQueue",
    "Identifier": "10599910-51ca-4834-8bf4-6686e3674214",
    "Timestamp": "2024-09-10T10:28:12.867Z",
    "Parameters": {
        "Queue": "Storage"

Q & intent name is same.
It should transfer to respective Q successfully.

What is the error? For tips on asking a good question, please see: How do I ask a good question?

Error is not specify in cloudwatch logs, just the result is  "Error"
